# How do I forward headers to different services in Kubernetes (Istio)

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, istio

I have a sample application (web-app, backend-1, backend-2) deployed on minikube all under a JWT policy, and they all have proper destination rules, Istio sidecar and MTLS enabled in order to secure the east-west traffic.

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: oidc
spec:
  targets:
  - name: web-app
  - name: backend-1
  - name: backend-2
  peers:
  - mtls: {}
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "http://myurl/auth/realms/test"
      jwksUri: "http://myurl/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

When I run the following command I receive a 401 unauthorized response when requesting the data from the backend, which is due to $TOKEN not being forwarded to backend-1 and backend-2 headers during the http request.

```
$> curl http://minikubeip/api "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Is there a way to forward http headers to backend-1 and backend-2 using native kubernetes/istio? Am I forced to make application code changes to accomplish this?

**Edit:**
This is the error I get after applying my oidc policy. When I curl web-app with the auth token I get

> {"errors":[{"code":"APP_ERROR_CODE","message":"401 Unauthorized"}

Note that when I curl backend-1 or backend-2 with the same auth-token I get the appropriate data. Also, there is no other destination rule/policy applied to these services currently, policy enforcement is on, and my istio version is 1.1.15.
This is the policy I am applying:

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
spec:
  # peers:
  # - mtls: {}
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "http://10.148.199.140:8080/auth/realms/test"
      jwksUri: "http://10.148.199.140:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Comment: [Policy](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/) enforcement by default is off. Did you enable it?

Comment: @jt97 It was off when I checked but I enabled it and got `UNAVAILABLE:upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure` on all my services. I also fail to see how this would propagate the authorization bearer token (also because I did research online and couldn't find out what enabling policy enforcement actually does)

Comment: Sorry, i gave You only link to istioctl if You would have to change it, there is link to informations about [policy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/enabling-policy/), it should be `disablePolicyChecks: false` and more [informations](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#Policy) what policy does, Could You please provide me information about your istio version and which type of [authentication](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/) You use?

Comment: **Istio version**: 1.1.15,  
**Auth**: Keycloak OIDC

@jt97 I'm still a little confused - should the token be propagated to backend-1 and backend-2 without any other changes?

Comment: As @chd mentioned in his answer it should work, there are some links provided which might help You, i think checking the envoy logs is the fastest way to see why it's not working. Could You try `curl -H http://minikubeip/api "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"` or result is the same?

Answer (score 1):

> should the token be propagated to backend-1 and backend-2 without any other changes?

Yes, policy should transfer token to both backend-1 and backend-2

### There is a [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15122) , where users had same issue like You

A few informations from there:

> The JWT is verified by an Envoy filter, so you'll have to check the Envoy logs. For the code, see https://github.com/istio/proxy/tree/master/src/envoy/http/jwt_auth
>
> Pilot retrieves the JWKS to be used by the filter (it is inlined into the Envoy config), you can find the code for that in pilot/pkg/security

### And another problem with that in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988412/keycloak-provides-invalid-signature-with-istio-and-jwt)

where accepted answer is:

> The problem was resolved with two options: 1. Replace Service Name and port by external server ip and external port (for issuer and jwksUri) 2. Disable the usage of mTLS and its policy (Known issue: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10062).

### From istio documentation

> For each service, Istio applies the narrowest matching policy. The order is: service-specific > namespace-wide > mesh-wide. If more than one service-specific policy matches a service, Istio selects one of them at random. Operators must avoid such conflicts when configuring their policies.
>
> To enforce uniqueness for mesh-wide and namespace-wide policies, Istio accepts only one authentication policy per mesh and one authentication policy per namespace. Istio also requires mesh-wide and namespace-wide policies to have the specific name default.
>
> If a service has no matching policies, both transport authentication and origin authentication are disabled.

Comment: I tried to do as you said however the token was not propagated to the backend services. I checked the istio-sidecar and saw that the header was not present in backend when I made the call to web-app. I also added some edits to my original post if that clarifies anything.

Answer (score 1):

Istio supports header propagation. Probably didn't support when this thread was created.

You can allow the original header to be forwarded by using `forwardOriginalToken`: true in `JWTRules` or forward a valid JWT payload using `outputPayloadToHeader` in `JWTRules`.

Reference: [ISTIO JWTRule documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/jwt/)